# How can i find the following Poisson distribution when i have a non-integer value

Tags: poisson-distribution

I need to find the Poisson distribution of successes that occur in a 30 minute period based on a 3% per hour success rate, i know the Poisson distribution formula (P.M.F) but can't figure out how to calculate it as you can't factoral a non-integer.

Comment: Where do you have a "non-integer?"

Comment: Although the factorial is defined for non-integers (it's defined for all complex numbers except $-1,-2,-3,\ldots$), by consulting formulas you will see you never have to compute a factorial of anything other than $0,1,2,\ldots,$ if even that.

Comment: For many more examples (besides the duplicate), please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=poisson+distribution+%5Bself-study%5D.